# Search in a collection of nested objects

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have elasticSearch 7.4. I have an Address model and nested models 'parts' of type Entry:

```
@Document(indexName = "address", createIndex = true)
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, store = true)
    public String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String fullAddress;

    private String regionCode;
    private boolean customQuery = true;
    private boolean root;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, store = true)
    private List<Entry> parts;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, store = true)
    private House house;
}

public class Entry {
    private String aoid;
    private String aoGuid;
    private String code;
    private String offName;
    private String parentGuid;
    private String shortName;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
    private Integer aoLevel;
    private String postalCode;
}
```

I want to write a search on the AoGuid field from the Entry list:

```
@Override
public List<Address> findForHouse(String aoguid) {
    SearchSourceBuilder builder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    NestedQueryBuilder findByparts = nestedQuery(
            "parts",
            termQuery("parts.aoGuid", aoguid),
            ScoreMode.None);
    TermQueryBuilder findByRoot = termQuery("root", true);

    QueryBuilder findByIdAndLocation = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .filter(findByRoot)
            .filter(findByparts);

    builder.query(findByIdAndLocation);

    String[] strings = new String[]{"address"};
    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(strings, builder);
    try {
        restHighLevelClient.search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I call my search method, I get an error:

> **org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch
>   exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards
>   failed]**     at
>   org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
>   ~[elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1727)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1704)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1467)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1424)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1394)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:930)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   ru.evolenta.server.service.elastic.impl.ElasticQueryAddressServiceImpl.findForHouse(ElasticQueryAddressServiceImpl.java:117)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   ru.evolenta.server.service.async.impl.AsyncHouseElasticServiceImpl.lambda$saveFias$1(AsyncHouseElasticServiceImpl.java:45)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   ru.evolenta.server.service.async.impl.AsyncHouseElasticServiceImpl.saveFias(AsyncHouseElasticServiceImpl.java:42)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   **Suppressed:
>   org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host
>   [http://localhost:9200], URI
>   [/address/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true],
>   status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
>   to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"filter\" : [\n      {\n
>
>   \"term\" : {\n          \"root\" : {\n            \"value\" : true,\n 
>   \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      {\n
>
>   \"nested\" : {\n          \"query\" : {\n            \"term\" : {\n
>
>   \"parts.aoGuid\" : {\n                \"value\" :
>   \"2d598ce8-feaf-4fb0-9320-bcad370a5d52\",\n                \"boost\" :
>   1.0\n              }\n            }\n          },\n          \"path\" : \"parts\",\n          \"ignore_unmapped\" : false,\n
>
>   \"score_mode\" : \"none\",\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n
>
>   }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n
>   }\n}","index_uuid":"jqAtS-hiQOS08lKfa1nWqw","index":"address"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
>   shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"address","node":"G_1M-1l6SOyy7YHWBk2SSQ","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
>   to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"filter\" : [\n      {\n
>
>   \"term\" : {\n          \"root\" : {\n            \"value\" : true,\n 
>   \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      {\n
>
>   \"nested\" : {\n          \"query\" : {\n            \"term\" : {\n
>
>   \"parts.aoGuid\" : {\n                \"value\" :
>   \"2d598ce8-feaf-4fb0-9320-bcad370a5d52\",\n                \"boost\" :
>   1.0\n              }\n            }\n          },\n          \"path\" : \"parts\",\n          \"ignore_unmapped\" : false,\n
>
>   \"score_mode\" : \"none\",\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n
>
>   }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n
>   }\n}","index_uuid":"jqAtS-hiQOS08lKfa1nWqw","index":"address","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"[nested]
>   nested object under path [parts] is not of nested
>   type"}}}]},"status":400}**        at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:253)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]      at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:231)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]      at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:205)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]      at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]       ... 32
>   common frames omitted

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was able to solve the problem by writing custom Query:

```
@Query("{\n" +
        "  \"bool\": {\n" +
        "    \"must\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"match\": {\n" +
        "          \"parts.aoGuid\": \"?1\"\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"query_string\": {\n" +
        "          \"query\": \"?0\",\n" +
        "          \"fields\": [\n" +
        "            \"root\"\n" +
        "          ]\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}")
List<Address> findByRootAndAoGuidInParts(boolean root, String aoguid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your index template is the parts field of type nested?
if you can post your template will be great.